# CL: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed: CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE

Tags: halide

For test purposes I scheduled a fumction f, which calls a function g, as gpu_single_thread. Depending on how I schedule g, I get the above runtime error for different image sizes.
If I don't schedule g it fails at a size of 96x96
If I schedule it like so: g.compute_at(f,Var::gpu_blocks()).gpu_threads(x,y);  It fails at a size of 64x64.
If I do the same except the .gpu_threads it fails again at 96x96.

For a 32x32 image the options runs error-free.
Is there a way to get a little more information on the error other than that it is triggered by the report_if_error function from Pipeline.cpp?

Comment: Run with the Debug target feature set and the Halide runtime will print all of the features of the CL device it chooses, including the maximum work group size. 96x96 (9216 threads) which is a large work group. Usually it is more like 8x8 or 16x16.

Comment: It will also print out the actual work group size it is attempting to use in the call to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.

Comment: I haven't tried the debug target. I'll give it a go today.

Comment: Well I must have been sleeping, because I the 96x96 was a different error (CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES) so just removing the gpu_threads solved my problem. Setting the target to debug does indeed clarify more than setting the HL_DEBUG_CODEGEN to 1